# What is energy consumption of a circuit

Tags: power-consumption

I am currently working on my coursework, and one of the questions is about measuring the energy consumed by my circuit during the 5 μs period of the simulation as the power supply voltage, VDD, is varied between 0.75 V and 3.3 V (in step of 50 mV). Here is my circuit in Spice:

[image]

I am just wondering if my command is correct, or should I measure the whole energy consumption transistor by transistor, and if so, how should I do that.

Here is the energy plot based on my current command:

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fECPR.png]

Comment: Where does the energy to power this circuit come from? Hint: some DC voltage source. You could investigate what the current from that source is (plot it in the simulator). Another hint: Power = Voltage * Current

Comment: @ Bimpelrekkie, i think the energy to power this circuit comes from the supply voltage, does it mean that i should multiply the supply voltage by the current flowing through each transistor?

Comment: Did you try running your simulation? What value did you get for the energy? Does it seem reasonable? Can you plot the supply current and get a ballpark figure for power and energy?

Comment: *does it mean that i should multiply the supply voltage by the current flowing through each transistor?* If you have a battery with 3 different value resistors in parallel connected to that battery, how would you determine the power dissipated in each resistor? Would you use the total battery current or the current through an individual resistor? You should **know** this answer. If you don't then you're not ready for such a transistor circuit. The same applies to a transistor circuit. So why ask the obvious?

Comment: It looks like you're already integrating the power output of the supply voltage -- if so, why are you asking about individual component consumption?

Comment: @ TimWescott Yeah, i am just not sure if my method is correct for measuring the energy consumption of my whole circuit. Since calculate each transistor's consumption and add them up make more logical sense to me. But i am not sure how to measure each transistor's power dissipation

Comment: What is Ein and what varies between 0 and 77p, that's not a lot is it? I suggest that you take a huge step back and first analyze one inverter circuit (an NMOS and a PMOS), then put a square wave at the input of the inverter and see what happens to the supply current. Now, to me, what you're doing sounds like you don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: In addition to the power consumed from the supply, strictly speaking you should include the power consumed from each input. (Or at least satisfy yourself that it's small enough to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

If each CMOS pair has a net Ciss and Coss charged to Vdd the energy for each pair will depend on the frequency or number of transitions of switching that capacitance.

thus E= (Ciss+Coss) Vdd^2 * N transitions in time, t. for each pair neglecting static leakage currents.